# can not yum package , it pops strang error

Tags: linux, centos

I use Centos 6.5 server , openldap is installed in this server .

I just want to install vsftpd to this server by the following command , but it pops the error .

## yum install vsftpd

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

 libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 22 2013, 12:11:10)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I also checked , the openldap is installed .

## rpm -qa |grep openldap

```
openldap-2.4.39-8.el6.i686
```

Would advise why it pops the error that seems related to libldap-2.4.so.2 ? is my openldap have problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, does that openldap package you have installed contain that specifi library version?

Comment: Check out this post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118945/issue-with-yum-error-in-importing-one-of-the-python-modules

Answer (score 0):

Basically, do a

```
yum provides libldap-2.4.so.2
```

then install what it reccomends e.g.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ yum provides libldap-2.4.so.2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
     .... 
openldap-2.4.40-8.el7.i686 : LDAP support libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Provides    : libldap-2.4.so.2
```

so run

```
yum install openldap-2.4
```

if it's not found then you may need epel or some other repo. (i have repos: base, epel, extras, nux-dextop and updates and it was found)